# my code below loads a modal automatically,at the modal loaded i have a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the user checks the checkbox and clicks the close button the modal must not be shown again anymore. How can I do this?

```js
function popUp() {
  $("#LoadModal").show()

  var modal = document.getElementById('LoadModal')
  var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0]
  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal)
  
  function closeModal() {
    if ($('#checkbox').is(":checked")) {
      /*how to perform not to load again the modal???*/
    } else {
    }
    modal.style.display = 'none'
  }
}

window.onload = popUp
```

```html
<div id="LoadModal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>i want to hide this message by checking the check box below</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" />
    <label for="filled-in-box">Don't show again this button</label>
    <a class="closeBtn modal-action modal-close">Continue</a><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are there `<br>` tags in your javascript?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a jsfiddle of the code and explain a little bit better what you are trying to achieve. Your current code is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [browser local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this purpose. You need to set a flag in `localStorage` when the checkbox is checked, and display the modal if the flag is not available in your localStorage.

> Local storage is persistent through sessions and If you want to hide modal only for the current session use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

```js
function popUp() {
  var isModalShown = window.localStorage.getItem('loadModalShown')
    if (!isModalShown) {
      $("#LoadModal").show()
    }
  var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0]
  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal)
}

function closeModal() {
  if ($('#checkbox').is(":checked")) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('loadModalShown', true)
  }
  $("#LoadModal").hide()
}
window.onload = popUp
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="LoadModal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <p>i want to hide this message by checking the check box below</p>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" />
    <label for="filled-in-box">Don't show again this button</label>
    <a class="closeBtn modal-action modal-close">Continue</a><br><br>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.

Comment: I am going to describe the code now after editing. Internet not reliable so posted the code first, will update the logic now

Comment: there is an error sir it says: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
    at popUp

Comment: ok... there is no error now sir, but when i checked the checkbox and close the modal and go to other page and back again the modal loaded again sir...

Comment: sir where is ('loadModalShown') came from?

Comment: its running... stack overflow save me a lot

Comment: the id of checkbox is filled-in-box

Comment: but now i have a problem sir, in first testing, when i've check the checkbox and close it the modal never show again, and i want to try again, and refresh the page the modal never shown?

Comment: clear your local storage if you want to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the change function. This activates whenever your checkbox changes.

```
$('.filled-in').change(function () {
    modal.style.display = 'none'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, it is an improvement of Ashish's solution.
It uses [window.localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) which allows to save key/value pairs in a web browser with no expiration date.

If the user leaves the checkbox empty and clicks "Continue" `LoadModal` will be hidden, but then shown again.

On the other hand ***if the checkbox is checked*** and "Continue" is clicked, `LoadModal` will be hidden ***and not shown again***.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function popUp() {

        var isModalVisible = window.localStorage.getItem('isModalVisible');

        if(isModalVisible == 'true') {
            $("#LoadModal").show();
        } else if(isModalVisible == 'false') {
            $("#LoadModal").hide();
        }

        var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];
        closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

    }

    function closeModal() {

        if ($('#filled-in-box').is(":checked")) {
            window.localStorage.setItem('isModalVisible', 'false');
        } else {
            window.localStorage.setItem('isModalVisible', 'true');
        }

        $("#LoadModal").hide();

    }

    window.onload = popUp;

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="LoadModal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <p>i want to hide this message by checking the check box below</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box" />
        <label for="filled-in-box">Don't show again this button</label>
        <a class="closeBtn modal-action modal-close">Continue</a><br><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: stack overflow save me a lot